# Sending Data from wp froms to asp.net system

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress

I'm working currently on a Services website project, I'm using Wordpress to create the home page and blog.

On the home page, there is a button linked to another page contains a wpfrom to send the services requests to .net CRM system.

how can I send data from this form to a .net system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to make an API call to the .NET server.

Here are the general steps to make a call:

1. Send POST values from the wordpress button to the .NET page URL
2. Create a page in .NET that accepts POST values
3. On the .NET side do something with that information